# How To Write a Plug-In for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, ieaddon

The IE Developer Toolbar is a plugin that can dock or separate from the browser. I understand its much more difficult to do this in IE than in Firefox.

- How does one create an IE plugin?
- What languages are available for this task?
- How can I make a Hello World plugin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are a few resources that might help you in your quest to create browser helper objects (BHO).

[http://petesearch.com/wiki/ (archived)](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20110923191120/http://petesearch.com/wiki)

http://www.hackszine.com/blog/archive/2007/06/howto_port_firefox_extensions.html

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182554(VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182554%28VS.80%29.aspx)

http://www.codeplex.com/TeamTestPlugins

Comment: try putting a backslash \ before each of the parentheses in the url.

Comment: http://petesearch.com/wiki/
and
http://www.hackszine.com/blog/archive/2007/06/howto_port_firefox_extensions.html
are no longer valid.

Answer (score 9):

See http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/dev.asp for my favorite resources on this topic.